# Экспорт истории телеграмм канала в txt файл

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram, emoji

Прошу помощи - необходимо сделать экспорт сообщений (только текст) телеграмм канала в txt файл при помощи python(использую библиотеку pyrogram). Проблема - в тексте присутствую эмоджи, не получается записать в файл, часть строк имеют тип данных str, часть - NoneType, циклом пройтись и удалить эмоджи не получается. Спасибо за помощь!

```
    async with app:
        async for message in app.get_chat_history("medvedev_telegram"):
            file = open("all_history.txt", "w")
            file.write(str(message.text))
            file.close()

app.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если строка имеет тип None, то пройтись циклом можно так:

```
for message in app.get_chat_history("medvedev_telegram"):
    if message.text:  # Условие не будет выполнено, если message.text = None
        file = open("all_history.txt", "w")
        file.write(str(message.text))
        file.close()
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, это помогло, спасибо, однако, при попытке записи в docx файл библиотекой python - docx, записываются не все посты , а некоторая часть, не подскажите, чем это может быть вызвано?

Comment: Если вам помог ответ - прошу нажать на кнопку принять ответ. Насчёт docx, к сожалению, не могу подсказать